# implement proguard with cocoas2d

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, proguard, obfuscation

I have used **`cocos2d-x`** to develop the game. now i have applied pro-guard to it, resolved all the warnings. Finally I exported the api. The pro-guard worked fine for me. But when I tested the api, the application crashed.

Without proguard the application works smoothly.

Any solution for on how to implement proguard with cocos2dx.?

Comment: and what crashes where with which message?

Comment: I dont get any error messages. It directly comes out of the application.

Comment: Is this after you install the `.apk`? If not, then can't you run it in Eclipse and paste the `LogCat` trace here?

Comment: This is after I install the apk file that I have exported

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your proguard rules with us ?
Did you add a rule to tell Proguard to avoid obfuscating native methods ?

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class * {
native <methods>;
}
```

[Proguard Documentation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native)